# Solr search with reversed term?

Tags: solr

Hi what would be the analyzer chain to be able to search

Iron Maiden or Maiden Iron

I have this as my analyzer chain...

```
<analyzer type="index">
   <tokenizer class="solr.ClassicTokenizerFactory"/>
   <filter class="solr.ClassicFilterFactory"/>
   <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
   <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
</analyzer>
```

Edit:

Index and query analyzers are the same.

The queries I tried

q=name:"Iron Maiden"
q=name:"Maiden Iron"

Comment: what query you tried to use and what doesn't work for you?

Comment: Edited my question. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your analyzer chain is fine. What it will produce for "Iron Maiden" is following - "iron" "maiden"

To be able to find it in both straightforward and reverse way you just need to apply proper query. Phrase/Span query will do the trick.

Possible solution:

`name:"Iron Maiden"` and `name:"Maiden Iron"~2`, the only drawback about second query is that it will also find documents where `"maiden anyword iron"` will appear.

Comment: sorry, that was answer, that I've prepared before I asked question about your queries

Comment: Query analyzer is the same. :) I'll edit the question.

Comment: @user432024, so what you got when you search with one of your queries? and what's expected output? please share schema.xml and sample docs, that you've tested

Comment: As a term search name:"Iron Maiden" vs name:"Maiden Iron" only name:"Iron Maiden" works. If not as phrase search name:Iron+Maiden vs name:Maiden+Iron both work.

Comment: so you do not want to change query, but rather change analyzer chain?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138762/discussion-between-mysterion-and-user432024).

Comment: Not sure. Im no solr pro.